# Warning message everytime I use an npm command

Tags: node.js, npm

Fresh node install, new directory and everything, deleted all the previous files and this error is still occuring.

Steps to reproduce:
run `node -v`

> npm WARN config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
> npm WARN config `--include=optional` to include them.
> npm WARN config
> npm WARN config     Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.
> npm WARN config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
> npm WARN config `--include=optional` to include them.
> npm WARN config
> npm WARN config     Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.

No ideia why this is happening, it's not affecting anything other than just having a WARN message everytime I run a command.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by deleting both user and global configs for npm. It was the only thing that the full instalation didn't relete (I guess) so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error started to show up after upgrading from Node 16 to Node 20. Turns out, .npmrc file in my project had `optional=false` line. Deleting this line made the warning to go away.